# What is more optimal way of inserting image

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

I am using laravel. Speaking of load time on a website, I was wondering which method would be more optimal for adding images. Say I am uploading about 10 images per post. This maybe stupid but here are the two thoughts

1. Make a field in tables named ‘image’ ‘image1’ and so on until ‘image10’.
2. Create a separate table for image storage with the ‘post_id’ being the relation to images table.

So i was wondering which would be slower in terms of running queries. For an example I have this query.

```
$id = Post::first();
Image::where(“post_id”, “=“, $id);
```

In that exmaple, I am taking all the images from the Image table which is related to the post.

Now for the second query

```
$second = Post::findOrFail($id);
```

And `foreach` loop it in our blade view and take the image1 to image10. 
Which would be better in terms of query.

Now one thing I have noticed on my recent build is that it takes sometime to process some of the queries I had in the application and it takes about 250ms to just process the request and 15ms for downloading the content. I shortened some of my queries and optimized the code/query and I got it to 150ms processing time.

Which query will take shorter time to process and which will help cut down load time.

**Note: this is completely a thought and the examples used above are written in real-time and does not reflect any actual project coding.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

In your post model you can define the images relationship to tell Laravel how to find images. Using the separate images table is the best way to associate an arbitrary number of images per post.

in Post.php class:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Image::class, 'post_id');
}
```

Then to replace your first example you can do

```
$post = Post::first();
$images = $post->images; // this will be an array of all the images associated with that post.
```

Since you're asking about performance, you should look up [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). Basically once a relationship is defined you can tell laravel to load all of the relevant records.

```
$posts = Post::with('images')->get();
```

This line of code will get all of the posts and all of the images associated with each post. It will run two queries; one to get all the posts and one to get all the images.

```
SELECT * FROM POSTS
SELECT * FROM IMAGES where post_id IN (results from above query)
```

Then you can access all the images in a foreach loop without worrying about additional queries

```
@foreach($posts as $post) 
    {{ $post->images }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: This was the exact answer I was looking for. Basically my question was weather the query will give a load time. But the answer explained everything too well. Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 0):

it's better to user seconde option:
Create a separate table for image storage with the ‘post_id’ being the relation to images table.

and use 
in Post.php class:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Image::class, 'post_id');
}
```

to fetch them back
because by this way you can update,delete or insert new images limitless in you database

Answer (score 0):

If you do have multiple Image Make A Different Model

Post.php

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Image::class, 'post_id');
}
```

Image.php

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class, 'post_id');
}
```

This is best way 
This allows you to save multiple image, no matter how many images you have